# Prevent drag and drop on captions

Tags: javascript

the hosting company loads a script on all their sites that is allowing for the tabs to be dragged/dropped , however it is also causing the caption images within the same body_home page to be drag/drop , i have requested this be fixed but i don't think they are concerned. 
I am permitted to load my own jquery, javascript , html ,css onto the site to do changes , but i can not stop the host from loading this js file , so how can i reverse this ?  Here is a snippet of the portion of the js file i think that is causing this problem . 
I am permitted to load my own footer and header messages , so is there anyway i can remove what they are doing here , or reverse the effect on the captions ?

i cant find a way for the listener to be removed from outside.
They have used an anonymous function on the event 'domready' .
Does javascript have a feature to remove the listener from outside the anonymous method

```
window.onload=function() {
   if (document.getElementById("body_home")) {
      set_up_double_click_events();
      if (document.getElementById("homepagetabs") && document.getElementById("tab2")) {
         new Sortables($('homepagetabs'), {
            onComplete: function() {
               var parent = this.element.parentNode;
               var saveIt = false;
               if (typeof currentTabOrder == "undefined") {
                  currentTabOrder = new Array();
                  for (var i = 0; i < parent.getChildren().length; i++) {
                     currentTabOrder[i] = i;
                  }
               }
               for (var i = 0; i < parent.getChildren().length; i++) {
                  var seqno = parent.getChildren()[i].id.substr("tab".length);
                  if (currentTabOrder[i] != seqno) {
                     saveIt = true;
                     currentTabOrder[i] = seqno;
                  }
               }
               if (saveIt) {
                  var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + year + "/save_setting?L=" + league_id + "&TITLE=TABORDER&VALUE=" + currentTabOrder.join();
                  makeHttpRequest(url);
               }
            }
         });
      }
      window.addEvent('domready', function() {
         new Sortables('.homepagemodule CAPTION', {
            clone: true,
            revert: true,
            opacity: 0.7,
            onStart: function() {
               dndMovingModule = this.element.parentNode.parentNode.id.toUpperCase();
            },
            onComplete: function() {
               dndDroppedOntoModule = this.element.parentNode.parentNode.id.toUpperCase();
               if (typeof dndMovingModule != "undefined" && typeof dndDroppedOntoModule != "undefined" && dndMovingModule != dndDroppedOntoModule) {
                  var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + year + "/save_setting?L=" + league_id + "&TITLE=MODULE&VALUE=" + dndMovingModule + "," + dndDroppedOntoModule;
                  // alert("calling: " + url);
                  makeHttpRequest(url);
                  setTimeout("window.location.reload();", 250);
               }
            }
         });
      });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your hosting company injects scripts into your web pages? Get a new hosting company.

Comment: its not a hosting company , its a provider for fantasy football sites , they provide the information and each customer can customize the design

Comment: `Element.onmousedown = function(){return false;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#DIVID').on('mousedown', function(e) {
      return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put an HTML `class` attribute on all of your images that are producing the problem. Obviously, jQuery uses CSS style selectors. See the following example.

```
$(function(){
  $('.ElementClass').mousedown(function(){
    return false;
  });
});
```

When you `return false;` `onmousedown` it prevents the default behavior in most Browsers, which is to grab the image so the Client can drop and drag the image into into a new tab or window to view it with their Browser.

Comment: You should explain why the code you provided would solve the issue. Just dropping a block of code is not going to teach new users how to do it themselves next time.